# Workflow start automatically when an item is changed - Only working on items created by me

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint Designer 2013, I have a list workflow with the box for "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" checked. The workflow logs a statement to the workflow history, and then if a dropdown is set to Approved, sends an e-mail.

The workflow seems to work fine when I edit an item that I created, however it is not running when I edit an item created by someone else. (The item is edited successfully; I can see the change.) I know this because the history is only updated on edits to those items created by me.

That at least seems to be the pattern. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by using a 2010 workflow. Not sure why 2013 has these kinds of issues.